# Disable CamelCase in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am using WP.

Button texts and titles are automatically converted to CamelCase (each first letter of a word is turned into Uppercase).

How do I disable this?

Thank you!

Comment: When there's spaces involved, it technically becomes title case instead of camel. Title is aware of `the` and `of` and usually keeps them lowercase whereas camel would uppercase them, too. Pedantic, but might be important. Regardless, I don't think there's anything in core that would specifically do this, this sounds like it might be a theme/plugin feature. Can you show more specifically how/where it is being done?

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

Customize - Global - Typography - both Base Typography and Headings

And

Customize - Global -  Buttons for button titles